# Flutter. Play raw h264 from WebSocket

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, h.264, live

I'm trying to display live video in flutter coming from video server. Video server sends raw h264 video through websocket. I know that this video can be played in browser by jmuxer library. For now I only get h264 frames, but I don't know posibility to display them. What I got:

```
void getFrames() async {
//some auth stuff
  HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
  Socket socket = await response.detachSocket();
  WebSocket ws = WebSocket.fromUpgradedSocket(
    socket,
    serverSide: false,
  );
  ws.listen(
    (event) async {      
      print(parse(event)['data']);
    }
}
void main() {
  getFrames();
}
```

From that I got in console Uint8ArrayView's like:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 9, 240, 0, 0, 0, 1, 65, 154, 56, 18, 224, 163 ... ]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 9, 240, 0, 0, 0, 1, 65, 154, 84, 5, 184, 31, 114 ... ]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 9, 240, 0, 0, 0, 1, 103, 66, 192, 31, 217, 0, 180 ... ]
```

So question is - can I easily feed it to some flutter library to display video? If so, it would be nice to get some code example how to do it because I'm very-very new to dart/flutter and video processing.
Thanks!

Update: I dumped this as binary data to file and then muxed it with ffmpeg like *ffmpeg -f h264 -i input.raw -c copy out.mp4*, so that file can be played by VLC. May be there is a way to do this 'on-fly' in flutter player with help of flutter_ffmpeg?

Comment: For what it's worth, the examples you show are H.264 encoded in so-called byte-stream format (with the delimiter 0,0,0,1 between chunks of data). The first two lines are so-called interframes, which rely on the previous frame to decode. The third one is likely an intraframe (also known as an Instantaneous Decoder Refresh -- IDR -- frame) because it has a Sequence Parameter Set. See [this](https://yumichan.net/video-processing/video-compression/introduction-to-h264-nal-unit/). You need a decoder that can handle bytestream format. Sorry to say, I don't know where to find one for Flutter.

Comment: have you found any solution on that ?

Comment: currently, not found :(

Comment: @Doe could you share your current solution? I am having the exact same problem but cannot figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I’m doing something similar - using ffmpeg-kit to convert an h264 raw byte-stream in real-time using ffmpeg input pipe, and VLC Player to view the HLS output.

Please see my example in this comment:
https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/issues/460#issuecomment-1156876012

Hope this helps.

P.S.
If you managed to find an alternative solution to your issue by now - please share

Comment: This link is no longer valid.  Can you please share this example again?

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt there is a dart-only implementation for this (and will need some sort of platform interface).

If you only need to support web, then you are golden: you could just wrap the jMuxer library you mentioned with [this](https://pub.dev/packages/js).

If you need to support on other platforms too, then that is a bit of a unique situation. The "correct" approach would be implementing a Flutter plugin that uses an appropriate library based on the platform. However, the option that would save you the most time would be implementing the wrapper for jMuxer in a [headless web view](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_inappwebview/latest/flutter_inappwebview/HeadlessInAppWebView-class.html) and then use that headless web view to expose the JS API to your Flutter application, which can then be used the same way on many different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I am also the same, my video is UDP transmission / MPEG-TS encapsulation / video encoding is h264.
I obtained the h264 part of each network packet.
I thought it was simple: 1. use  2. Create a new player object 3. Feeding the h264 data to the player object constantly
Now it seems that this is not the case

> var bin = toUint8Array(parDataStr);

Comment: What player? Can you share part of your code where you use, create player object and feed it?